# Method for setting up time to equal a clock function

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

I am currently new to Python about a half a month or so, and I've been trying out an automation project using Tkinter as GUI. I am currently having trouble with setting up an alarm clock similar function wherein I would set a certain break time and if my clock function is equal to that time it would print something (this is just to test if it works) but I just keep getting an error.

Here's a scope of my code wherein I am having my problem:

```
from tkinter import*
import datetime
import serial
import time

class HCTIProgram3(Frame):
    def __init__(self, master):
        super().__init__()

        self.CmdTerminal_frame = LabelFrame(self.master, text='Electrical System Command Terminal', font ='Italic', padx = 10, pady = 10)
        self.CmdTerminal_frame.grid(row=2, column=0)

        self.Autolights_Label = Label(self.CmdTerminal_frame, text='Autolights:', font='Italic',)
        self.Break_Label = Label(self.CmdTerminal_frame, text = 'Break:', font='Italic')
        self.break_space_label = Label(self.CmdTerminal_frame, text='to', font ='Italic')
        self.break_colon1 = Label(self.CmdTerminal_frame, text=':')
        self.break_colon2 = Label(self.CmdTerminal_frame, text=':')

        self.Break_Entry1_Hour = Entry(self.CmdTerminal_frame, width = 5)
        self.Break_Entry1_Minutes = Entry(self.CmdTerminal_frame, width = 5)
        self.Break_Entry2_Hour = Entry(self.CmdTerminal_frame, width = 5)
        self.Break_Entry2_Minutes = Entry(self.CmdTerminal_frame, width = 5)

        self.Set_breaktime_button = Button(self.CmdTerminal_frame, text = 'Set Breaktime', command=self.set_break)
        
        self.Autolights_Label.grid(row=0, column=0)
        self.Break_Label.grid(row=1, column=0)
        self.Break_Entry1_Hour.grid(row=1, column=1)
        self.break_colon1.grid(row=1, column = 2)
        self.Break_Entry1_Minutes.grid(row=1, column =3)
        self.break_space_label.grid(row=1, column=4)
        self.Break_Entry2_Hour.grid(row=1, column=5)
        self.break_colon2.grid(row=1, column = 6)
        self.Break_Entry2_Minutes.grid(row=1, column=7)
        self.Set_breaktime_button.grid(row = 2, column = 2, columnspan = 7)

    def set_break(self):
        start_break = int(self.Break_Entry1_Hour.get())
        end_break = int(self.Break_Entry1_Minutes.get())
        break_time = datetime.time(start_break, end_break, 0).strftime('%I:%M:%S')
        if obj6.systemclock == break_time:
            print('It is break time')

class HCTIProgram6(Frame):
    def __init__(self, master):
        super().__init__()

        self.systemclock = datetime.datetime.now().strftime('%I:%M:%S')
        self.clock_label = Label(master,text="", padx=30, font=('Italic', '25'))
        self.clock_label.grid(row=4, column=1)

    def clock(self):
        self.systemclock = datetime.datetime.now().strftime('%I:%M:%S')

        self.clock_label.config(text=self.systemclock)
        self.clock_label.after(1000,self.clock)

root = Tk()
obj = HCTIProgram1(root)
obj2 = HCTIProgram2(root)
obj3 = HCTIProgram3(root)
obj4 = HCTIProgram4(root)
obj5 = HCTIProgram5(root)
obj6 = HCTIProgram6(root).clock()
quit_button = Button(root, text='Exit', padx=50,pady=10, command=root.quit)
quit_button.grid(row=4, column=0)
root.mainloop()
```

Here is the error:

[image: This is the error i keep on getting]

Comment: what is `obj6`? because the error says it is a `NoneType`

Comment: The `Nonetype error` is saying `obj6` is None (since in your code, you don't define it anywhere). An undefined thing (`obj6`) doesn't have `systemclock`.

Comment: Split `obj6 = HCTIProgram6(root).clock()` into `obj6 = HCTIProgram6(root)` and `obj6.clock()`.

Comment: always put full error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not comment) as text (not screenshot, not link to external portal). There are other useful information.

Comment: I used obj since i assigned systemclock as variable there but i think it doesnt work since it is inside a method? I dont really know.

Comment: Sir acw1668 hi also tried this one. Im not getting any errors but im not getting the print statement(‘it is breaktime’) on my terminal

Comment: Sir furas sorry im not really familiar with stack overflow it is my first time here so i dont really know the etiquette yet. Ill edit my post once i get on my laptop. Thank you for informing me

Comment: You check only once for the break time inside `obj3.set_break()`.  I think you need to move the checking of break time inside `obj6.clock()`.

Comment: HI SIR ACW1668!! THANK YOU SO MUCH! I JUST ADDED SOME INT VARIABLES SO THAT I WONT GET "NONE" AND MOVED THE BREAK TIME INSIDE THE CLOCK() IT WORKS FINE NOW THANK YOU SO MUCH!!!!